# Node.js application doesn't start on Azure Web App with custom container

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

I deployed node.js app to App Service.
Initially I adopted node14 runtime App Service provided.
However, puppeteer doesn't work on node14 runtime, I created custom container to use puppeteer/Headless Chrome.

I can successfully deploy, but server doesn't open.
Would anyone let me know what did I miss?

```
FROM node:14
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq libgconf-2-4 \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
  && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
  --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
  && rm -rf /src/*.deb

# It's a good idea to use dumb-init to help prevent zombie chrome processes.
ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Headfull mode
# Install dependencies
# To run Headful mode, you will need to have a display, which is not present in a server.
# To avoid this, we will use Xvfb, and create a fake display, so the chrome will think there is a display and run properly.
# So we just need to install Xvfb and Puppeteer related dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget x11vnc x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps xvfb

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer

# # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
# RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
#   && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
#   && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
#   && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules

RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install sudo curl

RUN useradd -m docker && echo "docker:docker" | chpasswd && adduser docker sudo

USER docker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) and [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) to start your application in the Dockerfile. You missed it. So When you create the image from the Dockerfile and deploy it to the Web App, there is no application run as you expect.